# tx_news call a single news item withouth the hash

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, tx-news

A typical news call looks like:

```
http://myurl/?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=4916&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=ef6e70673f8c8be5eddd03ad8bb8e220
```

I would like to change the uid in the frontend, but it does not work when I dont have the right hash for it. Is it possible to call a newsitem just by the uid or is it possible to create the hash in the frontend? Like

```
http://myurl/?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=9999&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail
```

while 9999 will be replaced with my uid?

Comment: Is it possible that this hash is for cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the cHash (Cache Hash) is related to the caching mechanism in TYPO3. The only way to get rid of it while keeping the cache mechanism working is to use RealURL. RealURL handles the cHash internally and therefore won't display it.

The default RealURL config for News can be found [here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/Main/Administration/Realurl/Index.html#basic-setup).

This will generate a link such as `http://mydomain.tld/news/detail/news-title` where `news-title` is the lowercase and space-free version of the title. If you want the UID of the news record as identifier, you can change the configuration by replacing

```
'alias_field' => 'title',
```

by

```
'alias_field' => 'uid',
```

Then clear the cache and your UIDs will be generated as configured.

You can also combine title and uid by using MySQL functions, e.g.:

```
'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(SUBSTRING(title, 1, 249), \'-\', uid)',
```

This would use characters 1-249 from the title, add a dash and then the UID.

Comment: but what if the news title should still be in the url?

Comment: @mtness I assume you down-voted my answer because it doesn't answer your specific question, but it still answers the question of the original author. So you might reconsider your downvote which is not really motivating. Nevertheless I will add information regarding your question to the answer.